# How to merge stock prices?

Tags: r, matrix, merge, finance

I downloaded 50 stocks and their prices. I would like to merge all those 50 stocks into one sample. How can I do that? My current code is (for 3 stocks):

```
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
library("tseries")
library("zoo")
library("quantmod")
#
getSymbols("AAPL")
getSymbols("ABBV")
getSymbols("ABT")
... etcetera
#
price_AAPL <- AAPL$AAPL.Close
price_ABBV <- ABBV$ABBV.Close
price_ABT <- ABT$ABT.Close
... etcetera
###
```

Thus, I would like to merge those "price_xxx". How can I do that ? 
[Here is what price_AAPL looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlUCg.png)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Reduce` with `merge` :

```
out <- Reduce(merge, mget(ls(pattern = "price_")))
out

#           AAPL.Close ABBV.Close ABT.Close
#2007-01-03   11.97143         NA  23.49581
#2007-01-04   12.23714         NA  23.94202
#2007-01-05   12.15000         NA  23.94202
#2007-01-08   12.21000         NA  24.02838
#2007-01-09   13.22429         NA  24.23950
#2007-01-10   13.85714         NA  24.17712
#...
#...
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Download the quotes into an environment `stockEnv` and then `eapply` over that using `Cl` to extract the closes and use `merge` to merge the result together giving the xts object `stockCl` .  Note that unlike base `merge`, here multi-way merge is supported.

(Also, full ticker data for particular stocks can be accessed using, for example, `stockEnv$AAPL`. Use `Ad` in place of `Cl` if you want the adjusted close.)

```
library(quantmod)

symbolList <- c("AAPL","ABBV","ABT","IBM","MSFT","GOOG")
getSymbols(symbolList, env = stockEnv <- new.env())
stockCl <- do.call("merge", eapply(stockEnv, Cl))
```

**2)** Alternately download the symbols directly into the workspace, apply `Cl` to each and `merge`:

```
library(quantmod)

symbolList <- c("AAPL","ABBV","ABT","IBM","MSFT","GOOG")
getSymbols(symbolList)
stockCl <- do.call("merge", lapply(mget(symbolList), Cl))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Base R solution that automates download of a set of symbols, merges and renames the close to `price_symbol`

```
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
library("tseries")
library("zoo")
library("quantmod")
#
symbolList <- c("AAPL","ABBV","ABT","IBM","MSFT","GOOG")
prices <- lapply(symbolList,function(x){
     getSymbols(x,auto.assign = FALSE)[,4]
})
priceData <- do.call(merge,prices)
names(priceData) <- paste0("price_",symbolList)
head(priceData)
```

...and the output:

```
> head(priceData)
           price_AAPL price_ABBV price_ABT price_IBM price_MSFT price_GOOG
2007-01-03   11.97143         NA  23.49581     97.27      29.86   232.9220
2007-01-04   12.23714         NA  23.94202     98.31      29.81   240.7277
2007-01-05   12.15000         NA  23.94202     97.42      29.64   242.6853
2007-01-08   12.21000         NA  24.02838     98.90      29.93   240.8871
2007-01-09   13.22429         NA  24.23950    100.07      29.96   241.8435
2007-01-10   13.85714         NA  24.17712     98.89      29.66   243.8161
>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, data returned by `getSymbols` is returned to the default environment. However, with `auto.assign = FALSE`, results are explicitly returned as an `xts` time series.   Using this approach, a possible solution is:

```
library(quantmod)
tickers <- c("AAPL", "ABBV", "ABT")
prices <- xts()
for( ticker in tickers) prices <- merge(prices, getSymbols(ticker, auto.assign = FALSE)[,4])
```

A variation using Reduce rather than the for loop:

```
library(quantmod)
tickers <- c("AAPL", "ABBV", "ABT")
prices <- Reduce(f = function(x,y) { xx = getSymbols(y, auto.assign = FALSE)[,4]; merge(x, xx) },
  x = tickers, init = xts())
```